# How to hide Top Parent Pages in Wordpress navigation

Tags: html, wordpress, navigation, navbar

I have two navbars on my page. One is the main one, the header, and the second one is displayed at top of each page.

Here is how it looks: 
[image: Here is how it looks:]

The lower navbar should show the childpages of the page in the top navbar (the red one). 
If one of the pages in the lower navbar have a child, it's going to be displayed as a new ul underneath the lower navbar.

The problem is now that if I'm on one of the "main" pages (the one linked in the top) then the links in the top navbar is being displayed in the lower navbar, and the links that are supposed to be shown there are shown in the ul that's underneath the lower navbar.

Like this (the links in font-color: red is the children of the children)
[image]

I understand why this happens, I just don't know how to fix the problem. I only want to show the sibblings if I'm not on a top parent page.

OK, so a try to make it a bit more clear: 
If on top parent page, show children.
If on children page, show sibblings and grandchildren.
If in grandchildren page, show sibblings and parents.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php

$sibblings = wp_list_pages( array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
    'echo'     => 0,
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title'
) );

$children = wp_list_pages( array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'child_of' => $post->ID,
    'echo'     => 0,
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title'
) );




?>

    <ul class="page-nav hidden-sm hidden-xs">


        <?php echo $sibblings; ?>
</ul>


<ul class="page-nav-children hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <?php echo $children; ?>
</ul>
```

**Update**

Okay so I tried something new. Now the top parents aren't displayed but when clicking on a page with children (top parents grand children) they don't display.

`$children` comes back empty on `var_dump`

New code:

```
    <?php

    if ($post->post_parent) {
        $ancestors=get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
        $root=count($ancestors)-1;
        $parent = $ancestors[$root];
    } else {
        $parent = $post->ID;
    }

    $sibblings = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=". $parent ."&echo=0");

    $children = wp_list_pages( array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'child_of' => $post->ID,
        'echo'     => 0,
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title'
    ) );

    ?>

    <?php if ($sibblings) { ?>
    <ul class="page-nav hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <?php echo $sibblings; ?>
    </ul>
<?php } else {?>
    <ul class="page-nav hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <?php echo $sibblings; ?>
    </ul>
    <ul class="page-nav-children hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look and see if any objects in the $sibblings array has the same post_title as the current post. If it does, use unset to remove it from the array. That way it won't be displayed in the nav.

```
    $current_post = get_post();
    $sibblings = wp_list_pages( array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
    'echo'     => 0,
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title'
    ) );

    foreach ($sibblings as $key => $sibbling) {
        if ($sibbling->post_title != $current_post->post_title) {
            unset($sibblings[$key]);
        }
    }
```

Below is if you didn't want to use unset but to instead use array push to push all of the posts that aren't the current post into a new array.

```
    $current_post = get_post();
    $sibblings = wp_list_pages( array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
    'echo'     => 0,
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title'
    ) );
    $sibblings_only_array = array();
    foreach ($sibblings as $sibbling) {
        if ($sibbling->post_title != $current_post->post_title) {
            array_push($sibblings_only_array, $sibbling);
        }
    }
```

If the above doesn't work then add your sibblings array dumped out so I can see exactly what is in there for data. Thanks!

Comment: But it isn't the posts with the same title thats going to be removed. It is the top parent page of all of the pages, as in the five links in the red header at the very top. They're never going to be displayed in the grey area, as they are now.

Comment: OK, so a try to make it a bit more clear: 
If on top parent page, show children.
If on children page, show sibblings and grandchildren.
If in grandchildren page, show sibblings and parents. Never show top parent.

Comment: Dump out your sibblings array and add it to your code.

Comment: I get it as a list with all the pages. Tried both `var_dump` and `print_r`

Comment: So it's a string? Regardless, I think you are going to need to show anyone here the data that is involved in those variables.

Comment: Its just the entire menu structure being showed when `print_r($sibblings)`

Comment: Updated the code, not with the data but with another way to maybe do it

Comment: Are you familiar with get_posts()?

Comment: Yes I am a bit familiar with it